# Javascript Function to change value on slide

Tags: javascript

I have a book slider, It was copied from this project. https://github.com/Coding110/bkt-album/blob/master/js/onload.js

I want to call my function when someone is sliding/changing/Fliping a page. I can't find which function is working while changing the page.

I want to add this function

```
let pageNumber = 1;

function changePageNumber(amount) {
  if (amount > 0) {
    if (pageNumber >= 12) {
      return;
    }
    pageNumber += 1;
  } else {
    if (pageNumber <= 1) {
      return;
    }
    pageNumber -= 1;
  }
}
```

I added this code in `onload.js` but the function is not being called, Or maybe I am not placing it in correct function.

```
if (Math.abs(self.delta_s) > 5) {
    // existing code...
  } else {
    // Calculate the distance swiped and determine whether to increase or decrease the page number
    var distanceSwiped = self.x_move - self.x_start;
    if (distanceSwiped > 0) {
      changePageNumber(-1);
    } else if (distanceSwiped < 0) {
      changePageNumber(1);
    }
  }
});
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Edit1:

in my `index.php` this is where I am calling it.

```
<div class="content_large_image">
           <div id="fb5-ajax" data-cat="your_book_name" data-template="true">
              <div class="fb5-preloader"></div>
              <div id="fb5">
                 <section id="config">
                    <ul>
                       <li key="page_width">918</li>
                       <!-- width for page -->
                       <li key="page_height">1298</li>
                       <!-- height for page -->
                       <li key="toolbar_visible">true</li>
                       <li key="lazy_loading_pages">false</li>
                       <li key="pdf_url"></li>
                       <li key="page_mode">single</li>
                       <li key="sound_sheet"></li>
                    </ul>
                 </section>
                 <div id="fb5-container-book">
                    <div id="fb5-book">
                      <?php
                        getimageformobile($pagedatesin, $stredition, $pgnum, $pgnum);
                    ?> 
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <a title="prev page" class="fb5-arrow-left" onclick="plusSCli();plusSlides(-1);">&#10094;</a>
                 <a title="next page" class="fb5-arrow-right" onclick="plusSCli();plusSlides(1);">&#10095;</a>  
                 <!-- BEGIN SOUND FOR SHEET  -->
                 <audio preload="auto" id="sound_sheet"></audio>
                 <!-- END SOUND FOR SHEET -->
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Here,

```
<div id="fb5-container-book">
                        <div id="fb5-book">
                          <?php
                            getimageformobile($pagedatesin, $stredition, $pgnum, $pgnum);
                        ?> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

is the code which is calling the book slide from onload.js